# Why does thread.join fail when called in destructor of global variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, destructor

I reduced my problematic code to the following. I have a class C that runs a member function on its own thread. In the destructor of C I want to cleanly exit this thread. This works fine as long as c is defined within main (1), but not when it is a global variable (2). In the latter case, I see that the thread function returns but that the t.join() hangs.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C
{
public:
    C()
    {
        stop = false;
        t = thread(&C::ThreadFunc, this);
    }
    ~C()
    {
        stop = true;
        cv.notify_all();
        if (t.joinable())
        {
            cout << "joining" << endl;
            t.join();
            cout << "joined" << endl;
        }
    }

private:
    void ThreadFunc()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
            cv.wait(lock, [&]{return stop;});
            cout << "returning" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    thread t;
    mutex m;
    condition_variable cv;
    bool stop;
};

C c;  // does *not* work (2)

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    C c;  // does work (1)
    return 0;
}
```

The reason I use a global variable is that it is actually part of a dll. When the destructor is triggered from DllMain on DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, the same problem occurs.
Is there an explanation and a solution to this problem?

Comment: Either `C::stop` needs to be an `atomic<bool>` or you need to lock the mutex in the destructor before setting it, otherwise you have a data race.

Comment: @Jonathan: I tried that but that is not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a deadlock. You are holding a lock that `t` requires in order to terminate while you are waiting for `t` to terminate.

Say as part of `t`'s detach process, it makes some calls into the DLL. How can the DLL sensibly handle a request when there is a thread (the thread that called `join`) that is partially attached to it? Once you start detaching, and until you finish detaching, the DLL is an inconsistent state and cannot sensibly handle thread attach and detach operations.

You really don't want to try to join a thread while your process is in a context you can't control.

Comment: That makes sense. But how can I then handle the termination? Not joining t at shutdown crashes the application (I think because according to the docs when t is destructed while running it calls std::terminate.

Comment: @Emile It depends on the circumstances. Perhaps you should detach it? You may need to acquire a lock and tell it that it's been detached. (Depending on what else you need to do when the thread terminates.)

Comment: There's nothing more to do. Detaching in the example code above works, but not in the real program. There I get a R6010 - abort() has been called, in mutex.c(38): mutex destroyed while busy. It is clear that I need another way to cleanup but my problem is this dll is actually a C extension module for a Lua interpreter, so maybe I can ask the Lua community if there is a way to clean up when a user presses ^Z in a Lua script. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Update: the book programming in Lua states: "When you are programming library functions for Lua, however, global and static variables are not a good approach". I guess I found out the hard way. It is clear that the solution is in the Lua domain, not C/C++.